# Browser agnostic hook to send asynchronous request upon window.onunload

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onbeforeunload, onunload, window.onunload

When a user closes a browser tab or window we want to implement a hook to send an http delete request.

My question is - can

```
window.onunload
```

or

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

guarantee the sending of AJAX requests or is there no such guarantee?

Now, we *don't* need to handle the http response, we just need a high success rate of delete requests fulfilled which means we need to guarantee the requests get sent before the runtime shuts down.

Also this would have to work across major browsers.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. Why would you need to send a `delete` upon unload?

Comment: "we need to guarantee the requests get sent before the runtime shuts down" no one system can give you such guarantee.

Comment: @Mathletics are you questioning the use case for this? I can provide the use case if you want. To keep it vague, we could send the delete requests before onunload,  but onunload/onbeforeunload provides us with a convenient event to use to initiate the deletes, if it were reliable, but it appears it is not reliable for this.

Answer (score 1):

No one system/browser can give you such a guarantee.

And yet wireless signal lost for example also qualifies as "session ended" I think.

The only option is to use some sort of heartbeat signals from client to server.

Comment: yeah, I think you're right...we can probably send the AJAX request ASAP, instead of waiting until the browser closes, but of course there is still a chance the browser will close before the AJAX request gets made

Answer (score 1):

[Navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) could be useful in your case, but it can only send POST request currently.